# woocommerce hooks warning "function not found"

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, warnings, hook

I wanted to use hooks in my woocommerce single product page to do some changes.

So I added the following code into my function.php in my child-theme:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary',' woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 35 );
```

Now there should be a second add-to-cart button on my product page.
But all I get is the following warning:

> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function ' woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart' not found or invalid function name in /home/userXXX/htdocs/vintagehome/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 298

You guys are my last chance to get this thing done!
Please help me..

Greets 
Alex

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
// define the woocommerce_single_product_summary callback 
function action_woocommerce_single_product_summary( $woocommerce_template_single_title, $int ) { 
    // make action magic happen here... 
}; 

// add the action 
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'action_woocommerce_single_product_summary', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: This is working! Thanks a lot!
One more question:

How can I add a second add to cart button in the function?
Is there a special code snippet for this?

Comment: @Alex: Please mark my answer as correct (✓) & second add to cart button for what?

Comment: the second add to card button iwas just an example - i figured it out by myself
thanks for your help :)